# make python not close after running program

Tags: python

see I kept running code and it kept giving pretty much no feedback.

example:

```
for i in 10;
    print("i")
input("press enter")
```

and I see a flash from the command line.
And I tried the input thing like 80,000,000,000 times.

Comment: Run it from an already-open terminal window, so that you can actually see the SyntaxError that's keeping your code from working.

Comment: If you're using Windows, this is a duplicate of [How to keep a Python script output window open?](/q/1000900/4518341) If not, some of the same solutions apply, although most won't work in case of syntax errors.

Comment: "The input thing" cannot work with your code because it has a syntax error, so your code does not run at all. The "flash from the command line" shows an error message from Python, then it closes because **Python** is finished running and does not want to wait for input.

Answer (score -1):

That example is not even valid python.

Maybe this:

```py
for i in range(10): print(i)
input("press enter")
```